# In what situation would C++11 = default constructor be different from a constructor taking no parameters and an empty body?

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor

I know that if a parametrized constructor is provided, the implicit default constructor is not generated.

If we have a constructor taking no parameters and an empty body it can play the role of a default constructor.

```cpp
class Box {
public:
  Box(int value) : x(value) {}  // parametrized constructor
  Box() {}  // default constructor
private:
  int x;
};
```

In C++11 we can write `= default` to specify that we want the implicitly generated default constructor to be present, even if we have already a parametrized constructor.

```cpp
class Box {
public:
  Box(int value) : x(value) {}  // parametrized constructor
  Box() = default;
private:
  int x;
};
```

I am wondering, is there a difference between these two syntaxes for specifying a default constructor explicitly? Are they equivalent or not? Is a constructor taking no parameters and no body really a default constructor or is it something else?

I want to ask, can there be a situation in which the constructor taking no parameters and no body have a different behavior than the C++11 `= default` constructor? Obscure and arcane examples are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that if you `=default` the default constructor, the type becomes a literal type, which makes objects of the type able to be used as `constexpr` variables.

```
class Box {
  // ...
  Box() = default;
};

constexpr Box box{};  // ok
```

```
class Box {
  // ...
  Box() {}
};

constexpr Box box{};  // error
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rWxhK9).

Comment: It's an aggregate in C++11, but it might be worth mentioning that it's no longer an aggregate in C++20.

Comment: @NathanPierson I made a mistake; neither type is an aggregate at all (they have a private data member). The difference is that the version with a `=default` constructor is a literal type. I've edited the answer. Thanks for the comment; I wouldn't have thought to check this otherwise.